# Why does the else branch not get executed?

Tags: c#

This actually is a working application. Albeit without much in the way of error trapping.

I am just trying to log the flow and am not reaching either the If branch or the else branch.
What can I do to make that happen? Neither side of the branch is logging into my txt file.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        LogMessage("Further Inside Try2 ");
        byte[] paymentData = (byte[])reader["payment"];
        strPaymentData = ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(paymentData);
        LogMessage(strPaymentData + " strPaymentData");
    }
    else
    {
        LogMessage("Payment Retrievlal Failed ");
    }
}
```

Comment: have  you tried to step thru the code?

Comment: If neither is being reached, then clearly `reader.Read()` is returning something that evaluates to false.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to check if reader has rows if you're using while reader.read(). If reader returns no rows, While loop will not execute. Hence the else will never be reached if reader has no rows.

You could rewrite your code as follows:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {    
        LogMessage("Further Inside Try2 ");
        byte[] paymentData = (byte[])reader["payment"];
        strPaymentData = ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(paymentData);
        LogMessage(strPaymentData + " strPaymentData");
    }
}
else
{
    LogMessage("Payment Retrievlal Failed ");
}
```

Comment: Lol, we both added nearly same code at same time...  Funny!  I'll +1 ya too.

Answer (score 7):

`reader.Read()` returns `false` if there are no rows to read.  Thus if you want to do special processing for no rows being returned, you'd need to move that check outside the `while`:

```
    if (reader.HasRows())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            LogMessage("Further Inside Try2 ");
            byte[] paymentData = (byte[])reader["payment"];
            strPaymentData = ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(paymentData);
            LogMessage(strPaymentData + " strPaymentData");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LogMessage("Payment Retrievlal Failed ");
    }
```

Now,**if** you know there's only *at most 1 row* returned (like reading on a primary key), you can simplify the code to just put the `reader.Read()` inside the `if` instead:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    LogMessage("Further Inside Try2 ");
    byte[] paymentData = (byte[])reader["payment"];
    strPaymentData = ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(paymentData);
    LogMessage(strPaymentData + " strPaymentData");
}
else
{
    LogMessage("Payment Retrievlal Failed ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have **just successfully read a row**, then clearly there is at least 1 row, so HasRows will return true. Move the HasRows test **outside** the "while"

Answer (score 2):

If you are not reaching either of the two branches, it must be because `reader.Read())` returns `false`. I don't see another way of making it happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your reader.Read() call is finding there are no rows either because the file is not open for some reason or is empty.  So checking for new HasRows after the read doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the logic:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
     //Process a row
  }
else
{
     LogMessage("Payment Retrievlal Failed "); 
}
```